# WooCommerce redirect add to cart to checkout for specific product types

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce i need to skip the cart page when adding products and redirect directly to checkout only for subscription product types.

I found the below code somewhere else which works for skipping the cart page based on product ID, however I couldn't get it right to use product type instead (see further below for what I tried).

```html
function woocommerce_skip_cart() {
global $woocommerce;
$product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );

if ( $product_id == 31 || $product_id == 31 ) {
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
}
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woocommerce_skip_cart');
```

**What I tried:** (it breaks the whole site: becomes a blanc page)

```html
function woocommerce_skip_cart() {
global $woocommerce;
$product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
  

if ( $product->is_type( 'subscription' ) ){
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
}
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woocommerce_skip_cart');
```

Any idea's how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised your code. try the below code.

```
function woocommerce_skip_cart( $url ) {
    $product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );
    if( $product_id ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'subscription' ) || $product->is_type( 'variable-subscription' ) ){
            $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
            return $checkout_url;
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woocommerce_skip_cart');
```

Comment: Hi @Bhautik, 

I noticed that when I added product variations to my product, the above code is not working anymore (doesn't redirect to checkout, but instead to cart url). 

How can I modify the code to make it work for product variations?

I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I found the issue, the product type for variable subscription is different: variable-subscription